# Warum „aus dem Englischen“, aber „aus dem amerikanischen Englisch“?

Tags: grammar

Auf der ersten Seite eines übersetzten Buchs sieht man zum Beispiel:

> Aus dem Englischen von [Name]

oder:

> Aus dem amerikanischen Englisch von [Name]

Die beiden Formulierungen erscheinen nicht konsequent. Warum lautet die zweite Wendung nicht folgendermaßen?

> Aus dem amerikanischen **Englischen** von [Name]

Comment: Häufig ist übrigens auch _aus dem Amerikanischen von X_. Gefällt allerdings nicht jedem. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Das Englische*, *das Deutsche* usw. (wie auch unbestimmtes *Englisch*, *Deutsch* usw.) stehen für die entsprechende Sprache in ihrer Gesamtheit. Dagegen sagt man *das Englisch*, *das Deutsch* usw., wenn von der Sprache einer Teilgruppe oder eines Einzelnen die Rede ist; in diesem Fall ist meistens eine nähere Bestimmung erforderlich.

Siehe hierzu auch den *Duden* zu den Stichwörtern [Deutsch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Deutsch) und [Deutsche (Sprache)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Deutsche_Sprache).

Comment: Bei Farbnamen übrigens ähnlich, denn obwohl _das Rote_ doch deutlich seltener als _das Deutsche_ ist, funktioniert es bei _grün_ schon besser, weil _das Grüne_ eine konventionalisierte Bedeutung hat.